# SVG file resizes when exporting from adobe xd

Tags: html, reactjs, xml, svg

**Hello**

I am developing a react app and I want to set a SVG for my header background.
But when I export it from adobe XD it's size will change.

This is the SVG code :

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1970.909" height="211.264" viewBox="0 0 1970.909 211.264">
      <defs>
        <filter id="Path_7" x="0" y="0" width="1970.909" height="211.264" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <feOffset dy="6" input="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8.5" result="blur"/>
          <feFlood flood-color="#396eb0" flood-opacity="0.278"/>
          <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" filter="url(#Path_7)">
        <path id="Path_7-2" data-name="Path 7" d="M0,0,1919.909.341V159.89s-164.931-36.264-428.15-36.264-349.451,32.555-624.725,36.264-259.615-21.429-476.374-21.429S0,159.89,0,159.89Z" transform="translate(25.5 19.5)" fill="#f05454"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

[This is a link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NaVL.png)

Edit: I can resize my SVG in adobe illustrator and every thing is fine , but I want to export and use directly from adobe XD

Edit 2: If I remove width a and height from svg it will not fit the screen again it's like it has margin.
[image: Edited SVG code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that this SVG could be optimized a bit. The path itself is fairly simple. So, in this example I scaled down the path. Now the numbers in the path are easier to overview. Then the viewBox can be simple as well. And now the filter is also more controllable.

PS: in your code you have two elements with the same id. That should be avoided.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 36 5">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Path_7" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy=".5" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".2" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#396eb0" flood-opacity=".6"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path filter="url(#Path_7)" data-name="Path 7" d="M 0 0 L 36 0 V 3 s -3 -0.5 -7 -0.5 s -7 0.5 -11 0.5 s -7 -0.5 -11 -0.5 S 0 3 0 3 Z" fill="#f05454"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `width` and `height` attributes from both the `svg` element and the `filter` element, then it will scale normally:

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1970.909 211.264">
      <defs>
        <filter id="Path_7" x="0" y="0" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <feOffset dy="6" input="SourceAlpha"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8.5" result="blur"/>
          <feFlood flood-color="#396eb0" flood-opacity="0.278"/>
          <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" filter="url(#Path_7)">
        <path id="Path_7-2" data-name="Path 7" d="M0,0,1919.909.341V159.89s-164.931-36.264-428.15-36.264-349.451,32.555-624.725,36.264-259.615-21.429-476.374-21.429S0,159.89,0,159.89Z" transform="translate(25.5 19.5)" fill="#f05454"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I've done that , not working :-(

Comment: @giant What do you mean by "not working"? Can you make a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) showing what you mean when you say that it's "not working" and link it in your question? That will help inform anyone who wants to help you what the problem actually is.

Comment: @jsejcksn I min the background of SVGis bigger than the SVG . I've updated the question and attached another image.